# Grails - Multiple user saving at the same time issue

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Here's the scenario, **User A** submits the form with date range **(Sun Feb 25 00:00:00 PHT 2018 to Mon Feb 26 00:00:00 PHT 2018)** and at the same time **User B** submits the form with the same date range as **User A**. I already have a service to check if the date range is already used, and it is working perfectly if **User B** submits the form later than **User A**, the problem is when they both submit the form at the same time the checker does not seem to work. I am using **PostgreSQL** as my database

Domain class:

```
/** Date Start */
Date dateStart
/** Date End */
Date dateEnd
```

Controller method:

```
def someService

def saveDate() {
    def dateMap   = [:]
    def dateEnd   = Date.parse('MM-dd-yyyy', params?.dateEnd) : null
    def dateStart = Date.parse('MM-dd-yyyy', params?.dateStart) : null

    /** Validate if date exists */
    def dateExists = someService.checkDate(dateStart, dateEnd)

    //.. 

    if (dateExists) {
        flash.error = message(code: "Date Exists")
    } else {
        dateMap = [
            dateStart : dateStart
            dateEnd   : dateEbd
        ]

        def saveInstance = someService.saveDateRange(dateMap)

        if (saveInstance) {
            flash.error = message(code: "Success")
        }
    }
    //..
}
```

Service:

```
def checkDate(Date dateStart, Date dateEnd) {
    def periodQuery = SomeDomain.executeQuery("SELECT d.dateStart, d.dateEnd FROM SomeDomain d")

    periodQuery.each { val ->
        def convertedDateStart = new Date(val[0].getTime())
        def convertedDateEnd   = new Date(val[1].getTime())

        if (dateStart == convertedDateStart && dateEnd == convertedDateEnd) {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}

def saveDateRange(Map dateMap) {
    def saveInstance = new SomeDomain()

    saveInstance.with {
        dateStart = dateMap?.dateStart
        dateEnd   = dateMap?.dateEnd
    }

    saveInstance.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

    return saveInstance
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a check constraint?

Comment: sounds like you are missing optimistic locking